# For loop into a set python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, parsing

I am attempting to create a set based on the name of the files that I am reading.

Code:

```
ext = '*.xml'
directory = './'
sets = {}

    for file in glob.glob1(directory,ext):
        print(sets)
```

Output

```
pom copy.xml
pom copy 3.xml
pom copy 2.xml
pom copy 5.xml
pom.xml
pom copy 4.xml
pom copy 6.xml
pom copy 7.xml
pom copy 9.xml
pom copy 8.xml
pom copy 10.xml
```

Expected output

```
{pom copy.xml, pom copy 3.xml, pom copy 2.xml, pom copy 5.xml, pom.xml, pom copy 4.xml, pom copy 6.xml, pom copy 7.xml, pom copy 9.xml, pom copy 8.xml, pom copy 10.xml}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I edited your question to correspond to the actual goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can simply wrap your `glob.glob` function call with `set()`:

```
import glob
ext = '*.txt'
directory = './'
sets = set(glob.glob(directory+ext)) # Using a comma with give you an error, you need to use a `+`
```

Answer (score 1):

Just append each `file` to Your set:

```
import glob
ext = '*.xml'
directory = './'
sets = set()

for file in glob.glob(directory+ext):
    sets.add(file)
```

One thing is worth notice:

```
[] = empty list

() = empty tuple

{} = empty dict
```

There's no literal syntax for the empty set. You have to write `set()` instead of `{}`.